# can not issue any command on freesshd server

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I installed `FreeSSHd` server on my `Windows XP` machine. Then i started FreeSSHd and created a user. After that i runned `Putty` to connect my newly installed SSH server. I entered my created user name and password in putty. I successfully logged on but i couldn't execute any SSH commands with putty. Only `HELP` and `DIR` commands answer properly. Other SSH commands like `LS`, `PWD`, etc. returns error message such as "`xxx command is an unknown command and can not be executed.`".
My question is simple. How can execute `SSH` commands via `Putty` over `FreeSSHd` server on `Windows machine`. I want to simulate a file copy. I think i should execute `SCP` or `PUT` commands but i couldn't success. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try "windows" shell commands like `dir` instead of `ls` and `echo %cd%` instead of `pwd`?

Comment: @VolkerK i tried dir and echo %cd% and these commands work correctly. So should i use windows commands insead of linux commands? I just want to copy a file to SSH server. Then should i use windows copy command in windows machine and linux copy command on linux machine? Do you know these copy commands on both linux and windows? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to transfer a file from a linux box where you have a local terminal session to a remote xp box running freesshd. Is there a special need to initiate this transfer from the xp box (i.e. through the ssh terminal session)? If not just type `scp fileOnLinuxBox user@xpbox:targetName` in a _local_ terminal session on the linux box; not via the ssh terminal session (which would launch the (p)scp executable on the xp box).

Comment: @VolkerK My development enverioment is Windows, so i installed freeSSHd on my PC to test SSH file transfer. However, deployment server will be Linux SSH server and Windows Client Machine. Imagine that my client application(or putty) will be running on Windows machine but SSH server will be run on Linux OS. At this configuration, should i still use scp command to transfer file?

Comment: You have to use the (p)scp command that is available on the box where you launch that command. You have a (local) windows box: just open a `cmd` window and use `pscp` (or any other scp application available on that machine).  There's no need to have another ssh terminal session before starting (p)scp.

Comment: @VolkerK Thank you. Your comments made it more clear. I will try to test over real Linux SSH server and i will see what happens. You can write an answer which i can accept by the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Commands like "ls" and "pwd" aren't "ssh commands", they're *Unix* commands. You'd expect for them to be available a Unix system (including Linux). MS Windows isn't a Unix system and doesn't provide those commands.

You can install these programs as third-party software if you like. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) is a popular free package.